# Safe removal of USB mass storage device not possible

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, safely-remove-hardware

I have a 1TB external hard drive. Whenever I try to safely remove it, it says that the device is still in use.

I looked through all my processes and I can't find anything using the device. It's annoying since I always have to unplug the device, which I know is not good.

I recently installed a clean version of Windows 7 and the problem still occurs. What could be the cause?

Comment: Try using [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which service is accessing the usb drive.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use the process monitor. I opened it, and it's just filled with processes that access files/registry data. How do I know if it's accessing that hard drive?

Comment: Go to `task manager`->`performance`->`resource monitor`->`disk` . In `disk activity` , sort by `file` . See if any file from the drive is being accessed

Comment: when you mean clean, does that mean you haven't installed an antivirus. Usually those things love to make hooks to external files

Comment: As a dirty work-around in the meantime, you could just shut down the machine before unplugging it.

Comment: I've got the same problem and found no solution.  So I just sleep the box (it's a laptop, so that's just closing the lid) and wait 10 seconds for the drive to power down (which it does about 90% of the time -- you can hear it).  Then I unplug.

Comment: Have a look at [DiskMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646.aspx) from SysInternals. It will capture all read and write events to all drives. That will let you know if anything is actually being read/written to the drive. I don't think it takes into account caching, but at least it will help you know if anything is being read/written from that drive immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried changing the drive's specific policies tab to Quick Removal?

[image]

It would look something like that.  Otherwise, are you certain Windows is not indexing the drive.

And when you say "clean version of Windows 7" do you mean the ONLY things you have installed other than the OS are the hardware drivers?  Or do you mean that you wiped and reinstalled Windows 7 and the drivers, and all the software you normally use?

Comment: I found the policies tab, and it says "quick removal". Now, how would I make sure that windows is not indexing the drive? Also, when i said "clean version", i meant that i wiped everything and reinstalled windows7 + drivers + normal software

Comment: Device Manager - expand Disc Drives - right click on the drive in question, choose properties.  Click on Policies tab.   And you are sure that this "normal" software isn't still accessing the drive in some way?

Comment: So the policies tab says that it's in "quick removal" mode. And i really don't have much software on this thing right now. I can't think of any software that would be accessing the hard drive. Any other ideas?

Comment: @de1337ed -- Note that the text with that option implies that you don't need to click "remove" to remove the device.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading [unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/download/cabc22fdclick2a03b6da17791d9855e0d5f4/) from here and right click on drive and click on unlocker.Now choose kill all processes and then try to safely remove it

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have 2 ways..

1. Use third party software.
2. Do it manual.

1.Third party softwares.

- IObit Unlocker
- unlocker

2.Manual methods

1. Press “Ctrl”+ “Alt”+ “Del” together, then the Task Manager window will appear. Click Process tab, and search for “rundll32.exe” under the Image Name. Select the “rundll32”process, and click End Process. Then you can remove your USB device safely. If there are more than one “rundll32”process, you need to end all of them.
2. Try to empty your clipboard.
   when we copy a files from USB drive, the file will be put in the clipboard of the system and always keep a stand-by state. If we want to remove the USB drive at this moment, then the prompt will exit. so Try to empty your clipboard

source - http://www.gogorapid.com/how-to-fix-problem-ejecting-usb-mass-storage-device/

Comment: Or just set the "quick removal" attribute and, after it's had a chance to "take", unplug the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, it was caused by a task monitoring a directory for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it won't matter if you unplug your USB device when it's not performing data operations. However, if you really want to use the safely remove your device feature but it doesn't work, A tricky solution is available. You only need to end your explorer.exe process at windows task manager. Then at the time when explorer.exe is reloaded, you perform the safely remove.